# Nginx returning 500 on double slash in query param

Tags: http, url, nginx, parameters, http-status-code-500

I am receiving a 500 error after passing a param via query string like this:

```
https://my-website/namespace/resource/endpoint?myparam=//some/param
```

The exact param is "//some/param/". I have heard about the *merge_slashes* option in nginx but I would prefer to keep my double slash instead of merging it into one and avoid getting such an error in these cases.

Everything is okay if I manually switch "/" to "%2F" in the URL, but I would also prefer to avoid escaping it in the code calling my endpoint. Is there any way of configuring this behavior directly in nginx?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a problem of Nginx. It's a problem of your backend.

Comment: Actually the request does not even pass through the nginx so my backend will never receive it if I use the doubleslash.